# How to find the address of an auto_ptr

Tags: c++, smart-pointers

I have a function which accepts `unsigned char**` as parameter. I wanted to pass a parameter memory which was defined using an auto_ptr. I was trying some code like this:

`std::auto_ptr<unsigned char> pImageBuffer;
func(&(pImageBuffer.get()));`

But, looks like I am doing something wrong here. I get an error saying:

`Cannot take the address of an rvalue of type 'element_type *' (aka 'unsigned char *')`

Any ideas how should I go about this? I can't use `unique_ptr` or change the signature of the function.

Comment: This depends on what the function is doing with the pointer you pass in. Is it storing it anywhere?

Comment: Your mention of `unique_ptr` indicates you have a C++11 (or later) capable compiler and library You do know that [`std::auto_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/auto_ptr) was deprecated in C++11? And that it will be removed in the upcoming C++17 standard?

Comment: @TartanLlama the function assigns memory to the pointer I pass and populates that memory with the image.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg As of now I am stuck with using `auto_ptr`. Have been considering using `unique_ptr` later.

Comment: `std::auto_ptr` has been deprecated since C++11. Don't use it.

Comment: Voted to close as lacking example. The example shows the immediate technical problem of an imagined solution to a problem. The unspecified `func` is presumably about that real problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like the function you're passing the address of the pointer to needs to modify the address being pointed to (rather than the underlying object). You can't do this directly through an `auto_ptr` (you're trying to take the address of the return value of `auto_ptr::get` - this is illegal because its an `rvalue`). You need to create a temporary variable to hold the raw pointer first. I would recommend this:

```
unsigned char* tmpPtr;
func(&tmpPtr);
std::auto_ptr<unsigned char> pImageBuffer(tmpPtr);
```

This is of course assuming the function expects you to take ownership of the thing it is setting `tmpPtr` to point to.

Comment: As an alternative, the OP could use [`get`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/auto_ptr/get) to extract the current pointer (if it's needed) and then [`reset`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/auto_ptr/reset) to reset the wrapped pointer after the call.

Comment: That's true, but he would still need to create a local temp variable to store it in (otherwise you're trying to take the address of an `rvalue`, which is illegal)